# KafkaTemplate-Send-Request gives NotLeaderOrFollowerException

Tags: apache-kafka

Exception: `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.`

I have following configs:

```
    p.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094);
    p.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    p.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    p.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, ProducerAckMode.ALL.getType());

    p.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");

    p.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "10");
```

And my topic looks like:

```
TopicBuilder.name("test-topic-10")
                .partitions(3)
                .replicas(3)
                .build()
```

And I have 3 brokers:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094
```

And I send it like that:

```
SendResult<String, Object> result = arilKafkaTemplate.send("test-topic-10", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "data").get();
        RecordMetadata metadata = result.getRecordMetadata();
```

Is there any suggestion why I get this exception?

Ongoing exceptions:

```
Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test-topic-10-1 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now
2024-03-11T20:35:28.207+03:00  WARN 16076 --- [ad | producer-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Got error produce response with correlation id 20 on topic-partition test-topic-10-1, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER
```

Comment: What happens when you only run one broker locally and so have only one replica? I think there's a server configuration that is incorrect, such as `advertised.listeners`

Comment: yes it was related with docker-compose ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed docker-compose ports like below

```
 kafka:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - "9595:9595"
    environment:

      # Zookeeper
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://kafka:9595
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
```

before, it was like: (and it doesn’t work)

```
ports:
   - "9595:9092"
```